# NFC P2P - SNEP Client / Server

Tags: server, client, nfc, p2p

As i wrote in another post (["Symmetry Procedure" in NFC P2P LLCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663479/symmetry-procedure-in-nfc-p2p-llcp)) i'm currently trying to implement the LLCP & SNEP protocol on a PN532 chip.
The question i had in the other post was about the Symmetry Procedure as defined in LLCP which allows
to actually bypass the original Initiator / Target roles (command / response) i.e. gives each peer device
the change to send a message at any time.

If i got it right, the SNEP-protocol defines a Client / Server approach. The role is actually defined at
the LLCP-level when one device (client) sends a CONN-PDU to the peer device (server). 
Afterwards the client can send NDEF-messages to the server by using a "PUT Request" as defined in SNEP.

Let's assume now, the client has sent it's NDEF message to the server and - depending on the application - 
the peer device which currently acts as a server wants to send a new (not a response) NDEF message back to the
current client.

My assumption is that the current server would send a new CONN-PDU to the current client and in case this succeeds,
both both devices change their initial roles i.e. the initial client becomes now the server etc.

What happens to the initially established connection ? Will it be closed or can still exist in parallel to the new one ?

In addition (if my assumption from above is correct), is it also necessary on the NFC MAC level that the Client / Server change
mandates also a change of the Initiator / Target roles or can both devices stay in their initial (MAC) modes ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: and btw, if you liked my answer to your previous question linked above, why not give it an upvote and accept it?

Comment: Sorry, i'm quite new to Stack Overflow :-) - It's done. Again - Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i got it right, the SNEP-protocol defines a Client / Server
>   approach. The role is actually defined at the LLCP-level when one
>   device (client) sends a CONN-PDU to the peer device (server).

No, that's not how it works. The role is not defined that way. It is not obvious from the specification, but each peer usually is a client and a server at the same time.

Note that the spec section 6.1 "Functional Description" defines the following default behavior:

> The default server SHALL NOT accept Get requests.

That means, that a client is in general not allowed to request NDEF messages. The client is supposed to push it's own message if available.

The usual message flow in SNEP looks like this:

- Initial state: LLCP link is down. Each peer has a SNEP server registered and waiting for connections.
- On LLCP connect: Each peer that wants to send a message tries to connect to the opposing SNEP server using it's own SNEP client.
- On SNEP connect the SNEP server will: wait for a SNEP PUT command. It can then either accept the message or reject it:
- On SNEP connect the SNEP client will: send out a PUT command along with it's NDEF data.

Once each side has transmitted it's message (if they wanted to) they just leave the SNEP connections open. There is no proper way to close this connection anyway and there is also no cost associated with it. Each client can - at any time - always send an additional PUT request if they want to. This can be useful to esablish an bidirectional data-flow over SNEP.

Android won't allow this bidirectinal data-flow because they somewhat dumbed down SNEP a bit and don't allow a second message to be sent, but they will happily accept additional messages passed to it.

Comment: Ok - i think i got it now - thanks :-) And i assume the roles at the MAC-layer stay the same i.e. Initiator stays in it's mode, right ?

Comment: Yes, once the LLCP link is esablished initiator and target stay in it's role. LLCP makes sure that these roles don't make a difference for any higher layer protocol such as SNEP.